# Mapping relationships with custom names in Rails Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongoid, rails-admin, mongoid3

I am using rails admin, and it works fine except for a pretty big issue. I have custom relationships in mongoid, and rails admin is not allowing me to edit that field.

My relationship definition in mongoid:

```
class Content
  belongs_to :lesson, :inverse_of => :reading_material, class_name: "Lesson"

class Lesson
  has_one :reading_material, :inverse_of => :lesson, class_name: "Content"
```

Note that it is a rather straight forward relationship. But this is what I see this in rails admin:

[image]

Surely there must be a way to tell rails admin what to do here?

Comment: is the way to go to have `inverse_of` two times? isn't that supposed to be a circular reference?